# AutoMapper DynamicMap failing using previously created TypeMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I have An Entity, a DTO and a Model.

I manually create the mappings between the DTOs and the Entities, eg.

```
CreateMap<ProductPackage, ProductPackageDto>();
CreateMap<PackagedProduct, PackagedProductDto>();
```

For DTO to Model, I rely on Mapper.DyamicMap<> using the following method:

```
public static T Map<T>(this IData source)
    where T : IData
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    TypeMap map = source.GetTypeMap<T>();
    T destination = map == null ? Mapper.DynamicMap<T>(source) : (T)Mapper.Map(source, map.SourceType, map.DestinationType);

    return destination;
}
```

So when there is no existing type map, DynamicMap will take over and create the mapping for this instance.

If I have an Entity, with a Sub-Entity (Include(x => x.Children) aka Virtual List ), I map from Entity to DTO using the hard-coded TypeMaps, then when going from DTO to Model, I use DynamicMap.

After DynamicMap completes the mapping, it creates the TypeMap, it adds it to the list of Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().

My problem is, if I do an initial call using the dbContext, and there are no children attached to the initial Entity, and then a second call using the same methods, but the only difference is that there are Children included this time (because they exist in the database)... AutoMapper will use the previous Type Map it created mapping the previous result where there were no children, and this time... it will fail.

The code I am using to find the relative TypeMap is:

```
public static TypeMap GetTypeMap<T>(this IData source)
    where T : IData
{
    return Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().FirstOrDefault(tm => tm.SourceType == source.GetType() && typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(tm.DestinationType));
}
```

To solve this problem, I looked into removing the extra TypeMaps created by DynamicMap, but it doesn't look there is a way, other than Mapper.Reset() but this required me to re-create the hard-coded TypeMaps each time I make a call to the database.

What I have subsequently done, is added:

```
&& !tm.DestinationType.Name.Contains("Model")
```

to the GetType method.

Can anyone provide me with a better solution? Perhaps I am selecting the type maps too loosely? Maybe there is a better method to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: DynamicMap is intended for cases where you don't know the types at runtime. Why aren't you just using CreateMap?

Comment: Models are not accessible where I generate the Mappings.

Comment: Why aren't they accessible?

Comment: Because they a internal to another project. Structural reasons. My issue is removing dynamically generated TypeMaps from the Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().

Comment: So...make them public? That would solve this problem.